# STDEV.P with IF argument or Index matching

Tags: vba, excel

I'm in desperetate need o help regarding the stdev function.

I need help writing a sub function that counts the standard deviation, but only for the negative numbers from column F. I have spent hours and hours searching for a solution but I have yet to find one with an IF function, since I only want the negative numbers.

So I was thinking about using a IF function as in IF cell < 0

Below is the code as of now.

```
Dim ArtikelNummer As Variant    
 Sub lagerdata()

'Definera
    Dim NewSheet As Worksheet
    Dim RowCount As Long
    Dim i As Long, x As Long
    Dim check_value As Range

'Användar input för artikelnummer
    ArtikelNummer = InputBox("Skriv in artikelnummer", "Artikelsortering")

'Skapa ark med namn från input
    Set NewSheet = Sheets.Add(After:=Sheets(Worksheets.Count), Count:=1, Type:=xlWorksheet)
    NewSheet.Name = ArtikelNummer
    Range("A1:W1").Interior.ColorIndex = 37
    Range("A1:W1").Characters.Font.Bold = True
    Dim cell As Range

'Börja på rad 2, dvs under texterna
    x = 2
'Kopiera in data från "Data"-arket till det nya Artikelnummer-arket
    With Worksheets("Data")
        RowCount = .Cells(.Cells.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
        For i = 1 To RowCount
            If .Cells(i, 2) = Val(ArtikelNummer) Then
                .Cells(i, 2).Columns("D:D").Copy Destination:= _
                    NewSheet.Cells(x, 1)
                .Cells(i, 2).Columns("N:N").Copy Destination:= _
                    NewSheet.Cells(x, 2)
                .Cells(i, 2).Columns("C:C").Copy Destination:= _
                    NewSheet.Cells(x, 5)
                x = x + 1
            End If
        Next i
    End With

    End Sub
```

Comment: please edit your post, and load only the relevant section of code you need help.

Comment: I can't find any neither `stdev` nor negative number check in your code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure where in your code you need it, but this function should do the trick I believe:

```
Function stdevNegatives()
    Dim arr1 As Variant
    arr1 = Range("F1:F20")
    Dim arr2() As Double
    ReDim arr2(1 To 1)
    Dim i As Long
    For i = 1 To UBound(arr1)
        If arr1(i, 1) < 0 Then
            ReDim Preserve arr2(1 To UBound(arr2) + 1)
            arr2(UBound(arr2)) = arr1(i, 1)
        End If
    Next i
    ReDim Preserve arr2(1 To UBound(arr2) - 1)
    stdevNegatives = Application.WorksheetFunction.StDev_P(arr2)
End Function
```

You may need to pass it the worksheet to get the right range (and change F20 to whatever you need of course).